# May and might: which one to use

Tags: verbs

I found many information online on "might" and "may" and it sounds like most of the time we can use both of them, interchangeably.

However in this quiz, it seems like if only one of the two is correct and I cannot figure out why:

http://www.usingenglish.com/quizzes/answers.php?quiz_id=407

Here are three of the questions:

```
I was just wondering whether you ____ be able to help me.

may
might CORRECT

Q2 - ____ God have mercy on your soul.

May CORRECT
Might

Q3 - You ____ well be right.

may CORRECT
might
```

Can someone tell me why the ones that are considered correct are correct?

Comment: Use *may* in the fifth month of the year, *might* all other times.

Comment: Quit taking online grammar quizzes. They are stupid and can make you stupid. There's very little difference between _may_ and _might_, except in certain idioms. In politeness formulas, either is fine, but _might_ is slightly more polite. There is a magical use of _may_ in _May God have mercy_ or _May this house be safe from tigers_ that _might_ does not share; but it's rare and formulaic. For more on _may_, see [_May We Come In?_](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/1-MayWeComeIn.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

You can use either word, correctly. The answer was dictated by the author of that quiz.

Answer (score 0):

There are specific patterns that are more common for certain uses than others, and choosing the wrong verb would sound a bit off to a native speaker.

Example 1: When using "I was just wondering," you start off in the past tense, so **might**, which is historically the past tense of **may**, "sounds better" here.  It is sequence of tenses. Also, you're asking for a favor; and **might** is just a little more polite.  Additionally, using **may** can be taken for "possibility in the future" rather than "willingness to fulfill a request."

Example 2: When used in this kind of a sentence, **may** expresses an indirect imperative, or a wish on the part of the speaker.  It shares some semantic overlap with **let**: **May** the force be with you; **Let** the games begin.

Example 3:  Here, there is a lot of overlap between **may** and ** might**, as an expression of possibility, but **You may well be right** is a set expression, with over 20 times the frequency in 2000 as **You might well be right**. The key element to making it a set expression is the word **well**.  Take it out, and **may** still outperforms **might**, but only by about 2 to 1 rather than 20 to 1.

All that being said, I would hesitate to say that the other choice is egregiously wrong in Examples 1 or 3.  In Example 2, you pretty much must use **may**.